# C++ sorting numbers from smallest to biggest

Tags: c++, sorting, numbers

If I have the user enter 10 random numbers and I want to order them from smallest to biggest what is the best method to do this using the most basic C++ language.

Comment: Hint: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    vector<int> vec;

    vec.push_back(1);
    vec.push_back(4);
    vec.push_back(3);
    vec.push_back(2);

    sort( vec.begin(), vec.end() );

    for (vector<int>::const_iterator it=vec.begin(); it!=vec.end(); ++it) {
      cout << *it << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 21):

```
std::vector<int> numbers;

// get the numbers from the user here.    

std::sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());
```

Comment: @Jerry: why not use a structure that maintains ordering ?

Comment: @Matthieu: It's likely faster to do sorting just once at the end.

Comment: @kotlinski: while I agree with that, and using a `vector` for small input sets, it does seem a premature optimization! The asymptotic performance is equivalent O(N log N), so you're going for constant factor here, at the cost of complicating the code.

Comment: @Matthieu: I don't know, `sort` is quite explicit about what it does and `vector` seems like the simplest possible container. It just doesn't seem very complicated to me, I guess.

Comment: @kotlinski: Oh, I agree that this solution is simple. However it's one more line of code than using an always sorted container, and if you ever "forget" to sort (use a function before), then you're toasted. The sorted container solution also introduces the notion that there is no Silver Bullet, though `list` would be worse than `vector` here.

Comment: @Matthieu: Somehow I never use the sorted containers for the feature that they are always sorted, it is usually just not a very interesting property. I more use them for convenience, e.g. `set` has `find` member that is pretty nice if it is used a lot and fits semantically for your problem... in similar vein, `map` is nice just because it overloads `[]` nicely, not because the sortedness.

Comment: @Matthieu M.: I have at times, and it would certainly work. Personally, I've developed a bit of the same attitude as @kotlinkski. I need a bit more than just the fact that the container is always sorted to justify using it. A multiset is not only slower, but uses quite a bit more memory (data + 2 pointers per node). On x64 Windows, for example, a [multi]set of 10 ints has 40 bytes of data and 160 bytes of pointers. IMO, this situation doesn't justify that.

Answer (score 2):

Use a structure that maintains ordering: [std::multiset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/multiset/)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::multiset<int> set;

  for (int i = 1; i != argc; ++i) {
    set.insert(boost::lexical_cast<int>(argv[i]));
  }

  for (int i: set) { std::cout << i << " "; }
  std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Invocation:

```
$ yourprogram 1 5 4 6 7 82 6 7 8
```

(Note: the number of arguments is not constrained)

Comment: `for (int i: set)`  that doesn't look like C++ to me.

Comment: @kotlinski: C++0x new `range-based for` statement (**6.5.4 [stmt.ranged]**), I don't know if any compiler already implement it though.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirements. If you just want to sort them, and speed is only of moderate concern, an insertion sort would be fine for such a small n-value (10). Quick to implement (from scratch), and suitable for small set sizes.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //this is sorting min--->max without pointers
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {int n;
    cout<<"How much numbers you wanna sort? "<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    int broj[n];
    cout<<"Enter numbers: "<<endl;
    for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
    {
    cin>>broj[k];
    }
    int min=0;
    for(int z=0;z<n;z++)
    {
    loop:
    min=broj[z];

    for(int i=z;i<n;i++)
   {
        if(min<=broj[i])
        {
        }
        else
        {
             min=broj[i];
             broj[i]=broj[z];
             broj[z]=min;
             goto loop;         
         }
   }
   }
   cout<<endl<<"--------------"<<endl;
   for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
   {
   cout<<broj[j]<<endl;
   }
   return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Try adding some explanation

Comment: so this is just old school program with just if,for and goto loops..so the core of this program is in this "i" for loop which replaces numbers on different index on array..min is variable which we use for easier "transport" of that values..all in all my advice if you have visual studio or some program which can go step by step (line by line) when you run it,it will help you understand this concept...it's a bit longer but with this you will develop your programming way of thinking

Answer (score -8):

You can write something yourself, but really should use qsort function.

Comment: Quite the contrary. In C++ there's rarely (never?) a good reason to use `qsort`.

Comment: You would have been correct if the question was marked C (not C++)

Comment: to elaborate on @Jerry's comment, you should instead use `std::sort`.